# Charset encoding workaround for strftime() on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, character-encoding, locale, strftime

I thought I came up with the best solution for a workaround for PHP strftime() on Windows, and then a user reported trouble.

Windows has some limitations to strftime() and furthermore it does not support UTF-8. So I wrote a workaround for both of these issues but stumble upon charset problems.

This is what my code looks like:

```
function strftimefixed($format, $timestamp=null) {

  if ($timestamp === null) $timestamp = time();

  if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) == 'WIN') {
    $format = preg_replace('#(?<!%)((?:%%)*)%e#', '\1%#d', $format); // Don't mind this line
  }

  return mb_convert_encoding(strftime($format, $timestamp), 'UTF-8', 'auto'); // Charset is the problem
}
```

Error message

> Warning: mb_convert_encoding(): Unable to detect character encoding

As you can see 'auto' fails to identify encoding. The user is on a Czech windows installation, but I can't hardcode it to 'ISO-8859-2' as that will only help czech users and not other end-users who don't have the slightest idea what a Windows locale is or by which charset.

So what is the best possible solution for making some universal awesome workaround?

Note: The format is not the problem here. It could be anything, like %b %e %Y %H:%M. The charset identification is the problem.

Comment: You could use mb_detect_encoding() ? The PHP.net docs have examples :) [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)

Comment: Would mb_detect_encoding() work any different from
mb_convert_encoding(..., ..., 'auto') ?

Comment: Well, it would allow you to detect the encoding that it is currently in, then you can convert. Although, it may be best to just have a dropdown which selects what country you're in (then bases the encoding on that).

Comment: No, please! Don't recommend `mb_detect_encoding()`! It's close to useless. Encoding detection is **hard** and that function does not even try.

Comment: I know that `#(?<!%)((?:%%)*)%e#` is self-explanatory but... Could you please edit the question and explain what precise problem `strftime()` has and how your code tries to address it, for the benefit of dumb readers? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual](http://php.net/strftime), the issues that strftime() has on Windows include:

> **Not all conversion specifiers may be supported** by your C library, in
>   which case they will not be supported by PHP's strftime().
>   Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps, so **your
>   date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix epoch**. This
>   means that %e, %T, %R and, %D (and possibly others) - as well as dates
>   prior to Jan 1, 1970 - will not work on Windows, some Linux
>   distributions, and a few other operating systems.

Your code uses undisclosed parameters (`$format` and `$timestamp`) so what worries you is rather unclear.

However, the error message you're getting is related to **text encoding**, not date handling per-se. It's just impossible to handle text properly for unknown encodings, but you can **choose** the encoding produced by `strftime()` by selecting an appropriate locale:

> `strftime` — Format a local time/date **according to locale settings**
>
> Format the time and/or date according to locale settings. Month and weekday names and other language-dependent strings respect the **current locale set with [setlocale()](http://php.net/setlocale).**

Beware though that locale handling is unreliable in certain platforms such as thread-safe builds on Windows. If that's the case, you might need to dump `strftime()` entirely and choose a proper localisation tool.

Of course, you can always leave the default locale and just try to guess encoding from it but you'll probably need to maintain a database.

Comment: It is set to setlocale('czech') on Windows where in this case ISO-8859-2 is the encoding. But end-users have no knowledge of this and I need a universal solution for chineese, japaneese, cyrillic whatever. Windows does not support UTF-8 so strftime needs a workaround.

Comment: I see you've finally used my last tip. Glad it helped.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wish manual charset handling could have been avoided but this will do.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could come up with was to detect Windows locale charset and work it out from there.

```
function strftimefixed($format, $timestamp=null) {

  if ($timestamp === null) $timestamp = time();

  if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) == 'WIN') {
    $format = preg_replace('#(?<!%)((?:%%)*)%e#', '\1%#d', $format);

    $locale = setlocale(LC_TIME, 0);

    switch(true) {
      case (preg_match('#\.(874|1256)$#', $locale, $matches)):
        return iconv('UTF-8', "$locale_charset", strftime($format, $timestamp));

      case (preg_match('#\.1250$#', $locale)):
        return mb_convert_encoding(strftime($format, $timestamp), 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-2');

      case (preg_match('#\.(1251|1252|1254)$#', $locale, $matches)):
        return mb_convert_encoding(strftime($format, $timestamp), 'UTF-8', 'Windows-'.$matches[1]);

      case (preg_match('#\.(1255|1256)$#', $locale, $matches)):
        return iconv('UTF-8', "Windows-{$matches[1]}", strftime($format, $timestamp));

      case (preg_match('#\.1257$#', $locale)):
        return mb_convert_encoding(strftime($format, $timestamp), 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-13');

      case (preg_match('#\.(932|936|950)$#', $locale)):
        return mb_convert_encoding(strftime($format, $timestamp), 'UTF-8', 'CP'.$matches[1]);

      case (preg_match('#\.(949)$#', $locale)):
        return mb_convert_encoding(strftime($format, $timestamp), 'UTF-8', 'EUC-KR');

      default:
        trigger_error("Unknown charset for system locale ($locale)", E_USER_NOTICE);
        return mb_convert_encoding(strftime($format, $timestamp), 'UTF-8', 'auto');
    }
  }

  return strftime($format, $timestamp);
}
```